# Sort listbox items when clicking button 

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

In my windows phone project
I have a listbox binding data from xml

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox02">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel Margin="20" >
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Namee}"/>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Examinoo}"/>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Statuss}"/>
                    <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Idd}"/>-->
              </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

using

```
XDocument loadedCustomData = XDocument.Load("PeopleCustom.xml");
var filteredData = 
    from c in loadedCustomData.Descendants("Mathima")
    where c.Attribute("Id").Value == "1"
    select new Iatriki() {
                  Namee = "Ονομα: " + c.Attribute("Name").Value,
                  Examinoo = "Εξάμηνο: " + c.Attribute("Examino").Value,
                  Idd = c.Attribute("Id").Value,
                  Statuss = c.Attribute("Status").Value,
           };

 listBox02.ItemsSource = filteredData;
```

I want to sort the list by "Examinoo" when clicking a button

Here is the event handler for the button:

```
private void btn_sort_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    listBox02.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(
                new SortDescription("Content", ListSortDirection.Descending));

}
```

I get the following error :

> System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'SortDescriptions' and no extension method 'SortDescriptions' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: do you have the assembly reference `PresentationFramework.dll`?

Comment: no! where can i find it?

Comment: i'm working in windows phone application. I found the PresentationFramework.dll but when i try to add it, appears a message: "windows phone projects will work only with Windows Phone Assemblies"

Answer (score 2):

For the same problem, I am following this approach

After the XDocument line, remove your listbox line

```
listBox02.ItemsSource = filteredData; //remove this line and add the following 2 lines

ObservableCollection<Iatriki> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<Iatriki>(filteredData);
listBox02.ItemsSource = myCollection;
```

and then in button click

```
listBox02.ItemsSource = myCollection.OrderBy(item => item.Examinoo);
```

Comment: Thnks nkchandra! I'll try your suggestion!

Comment: like i said i'm completely newbie. Can you tell me please where i put the first code? Thank You!

Comment: I've already done this but in "new ObservableCollection<Iatriki>(filteredData);" appears an error: 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<WP7SampleProject18.PivotPage.Iatriki>' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments". Any idea? Thnks again!

Comment: also the error :The name 'myCollection' does not exist in the current context

Comment: For the second error, you have to declare your ObservableCollection before the page constructor and then define it after your above XDocument code.

And for first error, I am not sure why..ObservableCollection contains 3 constructors. Can you tell me what is the type of your filteredData, by placing a break point over there?